# Exclude matched DOM & children from selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I'd like to select a set of elements and their children from the DOM.

Then, I would like to run a set of selections on the DOM that excludes those elements, as if they were removed.

`.not()` seems to match both parent elements and child elements and doesn't properly exclude.

`.find(':not(.myclass)')` returns a list of about a bajillion elements and doesn't properly exclude.

What's my trouble? This seems simple but the functions I expect to do this don't behave as I expect.

I thought about cloning the DOM, removing the elements, and then running my selection matches on the cloned DOM... but that seems ***bad***. Like, a major performance hit.

What's the best way to do this?

Here's the code I have:

```
jQuery('html').not(".page-node,.quote").find(selector).each(function(){
//do stuff here to returned elements
```

`.page-node` is a body class and should return the body element on nearly all pages and exclude the selector from being matched on those pages.

**Edit:** I have created a jsFiddle to demonstrate what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/glassdimly/H4tJe/4/

Comment: `not()` won't match parent and children. Is pretty hard for anyone to help without being able to test against live html to see where your issues are. A demo on jsfiddle.net would help

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a `filter`, with a `closest('.page-node')`  etc. but it's hard to tell with a somewhat vague description ?

Comment: Alright folks, I've added a jsFiddle. Please let me know if it's unclear: http://jsfiddle.net/glassdimly/H4tJe/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Not()` *will* work with an appropriate *descendant selector*. A `*` following any selector will match all descendants (children, grandchildren etc). By applying it in a `not`, you can ask that all descendants be excluded from the match. As you also want to exclude the parent, include that in the `not` as well:

### e.g.

```
$(selector).not(".page-node,.page-node *,.quote,.quote *")
```

Which equates to:
"Not has class `page-node` OR and child/descendant of `page-node`" or "Not has class `quote` OR any child/descendant of `quote`"

### Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/H4tJe/7/

```
jQuery(document).find('.list').not('.exclude,.exclude *').each(function(){
    this.remove();
});
```

Which equates to "Find all items has class `list`, but exclude any that also have class `exclude` and also exclude any descendants of any element that has class `exclude`"

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to remove a parent of "selector," causing "selector" to not attempt a match of the excluded parent.

Comment: When did the rules change: "a set of elements and their children"? :)

Comment: @Jeremy John: Have updated your fiddle to show how to do it with a descendant selector.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for taking the time to explain that to me. It was the * selector that I was missing.